# Flutter show iconButton based on Map

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, iconbutton

i have a map like this:

```
static const Map<String, Map<String, String>> social = {
    'personA': {
      'twitch': 'https://www.twitch.tv/...',
      'instagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/.../'
    },
    'personB': {
      'twitch': 'https://www.twitch.tv/...',
      'instagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/.../'
    },
    'personC': {
      'facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/...',
    },
  };
```

It's possible to show iconButton, with the font_awesome icon, for each
social related to each person, and on click redirect to the link?, how ?

i tried like this:

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (_) {
                      return Constants.social[person].keys.map((e) =>
                          IconButton(icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.e), onPressed: {
                            print("example");
                          });
                      );
                    }
                )
              ],
            ),
```

but i receive the error:

```
The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int)'
```

the variable person can contain personA, personB or personC.

For example for personA i want to to show 2 iconButton one for twitch and one for instagram but for personC i want to show only facebook icon.

Comment: What Icon from the package do you want to use? What have you already tried? Can you edit your question to put these informations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView is a widget that represents [a list of widgets arranged linearly](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

You have multiple constructors for this widget. The one you used, `ListView.builder()` is the one suggested when there is a large number of children to be displayed. (In your example, if the Map contains many players.)

The default constructor only requires a `List<Widget>` and is considerably more simple. If you don't have a large map, I strongly suggest you to use this one instead. But since you tried using the `builder` one, you should do as follow:

- First, have your data arranged in a List. This way you can access the elements through an integer index easily: `List[0]`. Ideally you should have the data already in a list form, but if you need you can convert it like this:

```
static const Map<String, Map<String, String>> social = {
    'personA': {
      'twitch': 'https://www.twitch.tv/...',
      'instagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/.../'
    },
    'personB': {
      'twitch': 'https://www.twitch.tv/...',
      'instagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/.../'
    },
    'personC': {
      'facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/...',
    },
  };

List<Map<String,String>> listUsers = List().from(social.values);
```

For more information on these methods, check [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/Map/values.html) and [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/List.from.html).

- Supply the number of itens your listview will have through the [itemCount](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) parameter:

```
[...]
ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: listUsers.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
[...]
```

- Your error says the builder function needs to receive another integer parameter:

> 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type

> 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int)```.

This integer parameter represents what widget in the list it will be. Your builder function **needs to return only one widget**, and it receives the index parameter so you can know which one it is:

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: listUsers.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(children:[
                            if (listUsers[index].containsKey('twitch'))
                                IconButton(icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitch), onPressed: (){//Access listUsers[index]['twitch'] here
                                }),
                            if (listUsers[index].containsKey('instagram'))
                                IconButton(icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram), onPressed: (){//Access listUsers[index]['instagram'] here
                                })
                       ])
                    }
                )
              ],
            ),
```

This should be enough to have your desired result. As a suggestion, you can read the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) which has many good examples and explanations. The [Dart Language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) is also a great place for examples about the language. They are both well written and in this case would get you in the right track.